# Android: Self-Grant WRITE_SETTINGS Permission

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to enable/disable Wifi Hotspot, having device administrator privilege.

```
Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            return (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, wifiConfig, enabled);
```

Since it writes into the Android Settings, it needs the WRITE_SETTINGS permission.

I have a few questions regarding this:

1. Android documentation says it must be explicitly granted by the user,     so is it true for device administrators and device owners as well?

   > Note: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must
   >   explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission
   >   management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an
   >   intent with action ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS. The app can check
   >   whether it has this authorization by calling
   >   Settings.System.canWrite().
2. If not, how to grant the permission without having to ask explicitly ?